# If $X$ admits a nearest point to each point in every metric super space of $X$: every point like function on $X$ attains it's minimum value on $X$.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

If $X$ admits a nearest point to each point in every metric super space of $X$, then every point like function on $X$ attains it's minimum value on $X$.

**Definitions used:** Suppose $(X, d$) is a non-empty metric space and $u:X → \mathbb R^+$. We shall call $u$ a pointlike function on $X$ if, and only if, $u(a) − u(b) ≤ d(a, b) ≤ u(a) + u(b)$ for all $a, b ∈ X.$

The proof to the above statement is described in my textbook as follows : [image]

The proof for the part $(i) \implies (ii)$ begins from the green big dot adjacent to the words **for the converse** in the image above.

> Now, the proof above assumes that if $u$ is a point like function on $X$, then we can **always** set $d(x,w)=d(w,x) =u(x) ~\forall~x \in X$.
>
> How is this always possible?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can certainly extend the definition of $d$ in that way; the only real question is whether the resulting function is a metric on $X'$. The only condition that isn’t immediate from the definition is the triangle inequality. Suppose that $x,y\in X$; we need to show that

$$d(x,y)\le d(x,w)+d(y,w)$$

and that

$$d(x,w)\le d(x,y)+d(y,w)\;.$$

For the first we have

$$d(x,w)+d(y,w)=u(x)+u(y)\ge d(x,y)$$

by the definition of pointlike function. The second is equivalent to

$$d(x,y)\ge d(x,w)-d(y,w)=u(x)-u(y)\;,$$

which again is true by the definition of pointlike function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that we can always extend the metric $d$. But, suppose $u$ be any point like function on $X$. Then, why is it necessary that $u(x) = d(x,w)$ where $w$ is a point in the super space of $X$?

Comment: I mean why is it not possible that $u(x) = d(x,w) + k$ where $k$ is some other constant or something like it etc.

Comment: @Wanderer: You could use $d(x,w)=u(x)+k$ for $x\in X$, provided that $k\ge 0$: you would still get a metric. But why make things more complicated than necessary? The extension used in the proof quoted in the question works and is the simplest one that works.

Comment: Aah I see. The author having used the definition $u(x) = d(w,x)$ and his assumption of $u$ being any point like function on $X$ gave the impression that every point like function's value at $x $ is equal to $d(w,x)$

Comment: @Wanderer: I think that part of the problem may be the way you're writing it, as $u(x)=d(w,x)$: that makes it look as if you're defining $u(x)$ from $d(w,x)$, when in fact it's the other way around. You're given the function $u$, and from that you're defining $d(w,x)$ for all $x\in X$. That's why it's better to write $d(w,x)=u(x)$: you want the known thing on the right, and the thing that you're defining on the left.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. My mistake :)

Comment: @Wanderer: You're very welcome.